# Understanding Liskov Substituion Principle

Tags: c#, design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

My sample program like below;

```
    public class Animal
    {
        public virtual string MakeSound()
        {
            return "General Sound";
        }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string MakeSound()
        {
            return "Bow..Bow..";
        }
    }
}

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal obj1 = new Animal();
            Console.WriteLine("General Animal's sound id " + obj1.MakeSound());

            Dog obj2 = new Dog();
            Console.WriteLine("Dog Animal's sound id " + obj2.MakeSound());

            //Violate LSP
            Animal obj3 = new Dog();
            Console.WriteLine("Animal's sound id " + obj3.MakeSound());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Here as my understanding when we create Dog instance for Animal like obj3, we are violating LSP. Please confirm my understanding. If yes, please tell me how to achieve in this case to understand better. I think my coding is conceptionwise correct

Comment: Why do you think that breaks LSP? (It doesn't...)

Comment: Are you expecting it to fail at compile time or are you expecting a different output?

Answer (score 0):

You ar not violating Liskov subsitution rule.

Liskov subsitution rule in easy english -> if `Base.Method` leaves any invariants, then `Derived.Method` must mentain these invariants.

invariant is a state of an object which is not changed as result of a method execution.

for example:

```
public class MyInt{
   private int num1 = 5;

   public void print(){
      Console.write(num1);
   }    

   public void increment(){
     num1++;
   }

}
```

here, the invariants of `print` are only `num1`, because it is not changed. the invariants of `increment` are non, because it changes all of `MyInt` members.

In you example:

the invariant that `Animal.MakeSound` has : non. 
the invariant that `Dog.MakeSound` has : non.

the invariants of `Animal.MakeSound` are mentained in `Dog.MakeSound`, so the Liskov subsitution rule is not broken.

Comment: ok so i am adding one more class called woodenDog which is toy dog made from woiod. So he can't make sound. Here if I create WoodenDog class inherit from Animal I am violatingLSP. correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really violate LSP. I think a better example of a violation would be something like

```
public class Bird
{     
    public virtual void Fly(int height);   
}

public class Penguin : Bird
{
    public virtual void Swim(int depth);
}

public static class BirdExtensions
{
    public static void Fly(this Bird bird)
    {
    }
}
```

If I pass an instance of Penguin to this method, I might have to throw a runtime exception or something because my Penguin can't fly :(

You see that we made an assumption about the base class (all birds can fly), but now we have an example of a child class that doesn't meet that assumption (penguins can't fly).

Furthermore, because a `Penguin` is-a `Bird`, it has the method for `Fly(height=10)`, so I could technically do something like,

```
Bird b = new Penguin();
b.Fly(height=100);
b.Swim(depth=20);
```

Which violates the capabilities of the Penguin (he can't fly that high, he can only fly at 0, maybe...?).

Comment: this is not an example of liskov subsitution rule.

Comment: Trying to give a watered down version of the circle-ellipse problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem